# Create folder In roadming when new user logins win10

Tags: windows-10

I have Windows 10 PCs where theres multiple users from domain. And I want to upload program settings for each user when he first time loads hes desktop. In this direction: **user/appdata/Roaming** I need place a folder with some files. Is it possible to simply way to do this ?

Comment: Write a script (I would suggest powershell but batch will work) then google Windows RunOnce keys and use that to run the script the first time a user logs on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a domain simply create a User GPO that put files on the correct location. Or a script.